# Expertise from Delve via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph, delve, graph-api

We're migrating our current intranet employee profiles to Sharepoint / Delve and so far a lot of it seems very promising and the Graph API is great. However there is one field in the Delve UI that I can't find anywhere in the documentation on how to retrieve or set, but it must be somewhere since users can enter it.

It's the field for "Expertise", or Topics. Under the section "Skills and Expertise" it allows you to enter skills. These I know how to get from Graph API. Then the UI continues ... "You can also ask me about ..." To illustrate, see the image below.
[image]

The values Volleyball, Transformers, Food, Coffee I can't find anywhere with the Graph API. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same question, hunted around and could not find the answer. It's not listed on: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

But through some Trial and Error I discovered the "**responsibilities**" property DOES contain the "expertise" values (the "You can also ask me about" section). The description on the above API link says "A list for the user to enumerate their responsibilities" - so I assume its use/description has changed in the UI.

This query will return your Skills and Expertise (listed as 'responsibilities' - it's a string collection, same as 'skills')

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=displayName,skills,responsibilities

In your case the response would be similar to (if you added a few Skills):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,skills,responsibilities)/$entity",
    "displayName": "Dirk van Bergen",
    "responsibilities": [
        "Volleyball",
        "Transformers",
        "Food",
        "Coffee"
    ],
    "skills": [
        "Skill1",
        "Skill2",
        "etc"
    ]
}
```

You can use the Microsoft Graph Explorer to try this out:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer